# MacOS MySQL Gone Away and local networking issues due to GateKeeper

Tags: mysql, macos, nginx, macos-mojave, osx-gatekeeper

On MacOS Mojave 10.14.5, local services relying on TCP connections have connections randomly aborted, resulting in errors like "Mysql has gone away" and Nginx connection resets.

Seems like the Mojave OS is monitoring and blocking TCP connections, even if the firewall is disabled.

I managed to get MySQL working in a docker image, however this is much slower than native MySQL service. Same applies to NGinx.

A lot of blog articles online cover this issue with MySQL, recommending to increase wait_timeout and max_packet_size, which does not work in this case as the issue is most likely not with MySQL itself (in fact, local Nginx seems also to be affected).

Just spent 2.7K on a brand new MacBookPro and feel like I can't work with it...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Chatted with Apple Support, who recommended to do an SMC reset, which I have done twice and it did not help... They don't really offer support for the OS issues... Was about to return the MacBookPro and buy a Linux laptop...

... and then figured it out!!!

As part of installation instructions for a third-party VPN software, I have been asked to run the following command on my MacOS Mojave 10.14.5:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

This was to allow ALL applications to be installed on the system, bypassing System > Privacy settings (adding a third option "Allow all"), basically working around the GateKeeper service to allow for the VPN app to install.

This was meant to be disabling GateKeeper, so it won't interfere with the application, however it looks like GateKeeper is still doing something shady, and actually causing the networking issues.

Anyway, it was enough to switch it back and restart the MacBook:

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

in Terminal and reboot.